# Track's contributors within release

Tags: deezer

As for now, a playlist or release contains of incomplete track, it means the object doesn't have whole contributors list (feat. artists) just main artist.
At the same time, trying to get object directly, bypassing playlists or release, you will get the entire track object.
Is it possible to get a playlist containing complete tracks objects or maybe there’s a way to get tracks by multiple ids?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no possibility for now to get all track metadata directly from a playlist endpoint call, you have to get these informations by calling directly the track endpoint with the ID you want.